# How to make the <Text> enter new line when on end of parent?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm learning React Native and I ran into an issue where my  doesn't enter a new line when coming to the end of its parent container. It just extends the parent to display text in one line. How do I make it go into the new row?

Here is my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.eventContainer}>
  <Image source={this.state.uri1} style={styles.eventImage} />
  <Text style={styles.eventDate}>{this.state.dateEvent1}</Text>
  <Text style={styles.eventText}>{this.state.tekstEvent1}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here are my styles:

```
  eventContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 15,
    marginLeft: 20 
  },
  eventText: {  
    marginStart: 10,
    marginEnd: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 0,
  },
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a fixed width to the eventText container, this is an example but you can adjust it to fit your case

```
eventText: {  
    width: "50vw";
    marginStart: 10,
    marginEnd: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 0,
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! Thank you so much, I don't know how I overlooked that I need to set the width...